# Select by groupby and join where right side column values should be in one row

Tags: mysql, sql

ex : table t1 has id,name and table t2 has id,subname,t1_id(foreign key to t1).

```
# t1 #

### id | name ###
### 1  |vishal ###
### 2  |mote ###
### 3  |ashish ###
### 4  |bhosle ###

# t2 #
### id | subname | t1_id ###
### 1  |merce    | 1 ###
### 2  |tech     | 1 ###
### 3  |temp     |2 ###
### 4  |tech     |2 ###
```

where relationship is t1:t2 = 1:many.

Query result should be.

```
# t1.id | t1.name | t2_content #

### 1 |vishal |(0=(id=1,subname=merce,t1_id=1),1=(id=2,subname=tech,t1_id=1)) ###
### 2 |mote |(0=(id=3,subname=temp,t1_id=2),1=(id=4,subname=tech,t1_id=2)) ###
```

Any one help me to find out the query to select such kind of result. I don't want use any programming language to generate such result. only want using sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You basically seem to want `group_concat()`.  I'm an not sure what the `0=` is supposed to be, but this should work apart from that:

```
select t2.t1_id,
       group_concat('(', concat('(id=', t2.id, ',subname=', subname, ',t1_id=', t1_id, ','
                     separator ',') as StrangeFieldConcatenation
from t2
group by t2.t1_id;
```

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot but it is not proper query. I googled and designed exact query for my result. thanks a lot... I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

// to increase the t2_content output length

**SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000000;**

// actual query

**SELECT t1.id, t1.name, GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( '(id="', t2.id, '",subname="', t2.subname, '",t1_id="', t2.t1_id, '")' ) ) AS t2_content FROM  t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id GROUP BY t1.id;**